# Are roots of $\det(A-tB)$ with symmetric matrices real?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant, roots, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$, $B$ be symmetric real matrices $n \times n$-type. Let's consider the polynomial
$$
f(t)=\det(A-tB).
$$

If $B$ is positive definite, then it is known that $f$ has only real roots.
Is the same true for nonsingular $B$ (and $A$, $B$ symmetric)?

Comment: Can you give an example of a possible A or B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$, where $f(t)=-t^2-1$?